On Apollo 13, why did the CM pilot tape a handwritten note over the CM/LM SEP switch?

The pilot put a little sign that said "NO!" over the undock switches. Flipping either would have decompressed both modules and killed everyone instantly.
The official reason is that he wanted to make sure he didn't flip it accidentally. But the fact that those two switches were already covered by a metal guard with stripes on them, and the exclamation point in "NO!" make me wonder.
He had a miserable flu and was freezing and starving and thirsty and didn't sleep for three days. He spent most of that time just floating alone in the cold dark CM, thinking. I'm wondering if he was tempted to just end the suffering and play David Bowman in 2001: A Space Odyssey.

Note: It's surprising that they put these switches immediately below the DSKY. They only had to be used once and if they were ever used wrongly, the whole mission would be a disaster. You'd think they would've put them way up on the side, like the legendary SCE AUX switch.


Are we talking the movie or reality here? Apollo 13 movie did a lot of things right but is by no means a documentary, is there any source for the switch getting 'no' over it during the flight? My first guess would be a movie joke aimed at the audience to build the 'lunar model lifeboat' plot thread.

No, that happened. It's common knowledge. Apparently, uncommon.

And if you think about it, Tom Hanks was in charge of that. He was an Apollo freak ever since he was a little kid during the missions, just like me. He did a whole HBO miniseries about Apollo. No way he'd  put something like that in if it didn't happen. And that's on top of the fact that it actually did happen.

I forgot that it was also in Lovell's book, Lost Moon.

Ok, we have a source here https://www.americaspace.com/2012/04/17/we-show-you-on-the-mains-the-triumph-of-apollo-13/ including a claimed logic, so I learned something today. Re accuracy of the Movie there is a Jim and Marilyn Lovell commentary track that is interesting, since they mention not just things tweaked but often why the production did so.

Gagarin spent 10 days in comparable conditions and didn't complain.

@Vorac Gagarin  didn't have the flu, he had lithium hydroxide, he had heat, and he didn't blow the explosive bolts.

Most likely because it was a very irrevocable step where one of two closely spaced controls would have killed not just Swigert but the whole crew.
The Apollo 13 flight transcript does not have any direct mention of it, but does record several mental slips transcribing the large number of changes to procedures required for re-entry. Relevant to this question normal procedure would separate the Lunar Module at the moon and the service module much later, while for this it would be the reverse and the wording on the two controls was a somewhat ambiguous 'CM/LM' and 'CM/SM'. While the transcript records no radio calls about adding a sign it does have:

Lovell, from 1970 Technical debrief: "When we got to the point to jettison the SM, I thrusted up. Then, Fred went to verify that Jack was going to throw the right switch."
Swigert, from 1970 Technical debrief: "I wanted Fred there to make sure that I raised the CM/SM Sep switch and not the CM/LM Sep switches."
Haise, from 1970 Technical debrief: "I did go, but he had gray tape over the LM Sep switches. I figured that was enough of a safeguard and the way Jim thrusted, I needed to be there to control the pitch again with the TTCA."
Swigert, from 1970 Technical debrief: "You should have seen Fred when we got back there. I was all ready to go; I had the logic up and I was ready for pyro arm. Fred said he would get a Go from MSFN. Then I reminded him that we didn't have any telemetry and MSFN couldn't give us a Go. When I asked if he was ready, he looked at me with a wistful sigh, as if, 'Well, go ahead.' I put power up, and I could hear the relays clicking."

Which indicates that in the post flight debrief Swigert had both asked for a double check and put tape over the pyro fire control he did not want to activate. Note mention of tape rather than a written sign.
A more recent write up here has the following:

In fact, no step was more crucial than jettisoning the crippled service module and Swigert worried that he might eject the wrong module – Aquarius – by mistake, with his crewmates still inside. It might sound foolish, but one must bear in mind that all three men were exhausted, hungry, thirsty, cold and well aware that, despite all their efforts, there was only a slim chance of survival. To make sure that he did not screw up, Swigert taped a bit of paper over the toggle switch for LM JETTISON. The note to himself read simply: “No”. He triple-checked it and invited a bemused Haise aboard to verify that it was correct.

There is no source here but broadly aligns with the fact that he marked the toggle AND requested a cross check from Haise, and was concerned about his fatigued state and what would later be diagnosed as fever from infection.

Haise, from 1970 Technical debrief: "Yes. I wasn't sure what gave me the chills. I was back in the CM at about that time, and I had to go to the bathroom. I stripped naked in the 42 degree temperature ricocheted around touching bare metal, and it just chilled me to the bone every time I'd touch anything. You can't help but bounce all around in there. I was really cold for the next 4 hours. From that time on, it sort of began to catch up with me. I began to feel tired. Before that, I really didn't feel much effect at all."

The reasons stated above that he REALLY did not want to miss read or misidentify the controls and jettison the LM with the hatch open and other two in the Lunar module while feeling off colour would seem plausible, and being pyrotechnic in nature not like turning an incorrect motor or heater on unlike most of the other controls being operated through this period. In terms of his mental state, this was only a couple of hours from touchdown, they had started to warm the capsule up and been told to consume all the leftover water before jettisoning the LM.

@MissUnderstands - well having questioned your question thought I'd better do the legwork. Took longer because the Apollo mission transcripts are fascinating reading, including the note that the crew had tried ALL the medication in the onboard kit before flight to check for side effects. Given the range of effects and fairly strong stimulants and pain killers in there would have been an interesting couple of days.

@MissUnderstands found my copy of Apollo 13 and checked the Lovell commentary track - the 'no' sign is mentioned by him, with reason given as 'to not accidentally jettison the LEM with us still in it' which is slightly different again. I do wonder if there are one or more astronaut in jokes about this rather exciting control, possibly someone fired wrong one in a training sim and others made sure they did not get to forget...

I can guess that the crew followed some procedures more or less automatically ("blindly") after significant training (probably the purpose of the training was to make every move being remembered and automatic).
However in the case of things being broken in a way that definitely was not trained before, there exists the danger that (especially when very tired and exhausted) that you follow the automatic procedure you had learned without thinking.
Anekdote: When I as back in school (where I walked to school by foot) I wanted to go shopping the first day of school holidays, but I automatically took the path to school, until I realized that I did not want to go to school actually...
